# how to specify the type of document in lucene query?

Tags: lucene, mime-types, alfresco, cmis

I only want to retrieve "cmis:document" with no wiki, blog,... in a lucene search on Alfresco 3.4.7 but I can't figure out how.

```
TYPE:"cmis:document"
```

doesn't work.

Is there a way to specify multiple mimetypes in the query ?

Answer (score 2):

Alfresco supports different query schemes, and `cmis:document` makes sense only for [CMIS queries](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/CMIS_Query_Language). [Lucene queries](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Search#Lucene) use the Alfresco domain model instead of its CMIS view:

```
TYPE:"cm:content" AND -TYPE:"cm:folder"
```

Then if you want to filter [by MIME type](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Search#Finding_nodes_by_content_mimetype):

```
@\{http\://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0\}content.mimetype:text/plain
```

or:

```
@cm\:content.mimetype:text/plain
```

Comment: How can i filter only the documents without the wikis and all ?

Comment: You need to be a bit more precise in order to properly come up with the query you need. Which documents are you interested in? The content of the DocumentLibrary of any Share site? Or of only one specific site? All of such contraints can be specified in the query, you just have to express your requirements.

Comment: I want to search every sites for everything but links, folder, wikipage, calendarevent, forumposts, blogposts

Comment: updated the answer to include a sample of removing a specific type